# Controlling LPT hardware with web app on win64 client

Tags: php, windows, hardware, win64, lpt

I'm making a PHP-based web app which, on one of its parts, must control a device with the parallel port, I want it to allow port selection from the LPT list, not dealing if possible with hex addresses.

**Which options I have for controlling that hardware from the web app over the LPT port on Win64 clients?**

The goal of the web app is to replace an old delphi software, which (in the concerning module) controlled the LPT port by pointing to address 378h, sending a constant pulse (of adjustable duration) to pin 2 of the port.

This approach has become a problem when trying to use newer computers, as any PCI to LPT card gets a very different address range, and I haven't found if there is any support for that kind of signals on Win 10 x64, from microsoft or another provider.

Edit: The hardware will be on client side and the web app will be stored on a hosting service, pending to be chosen.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to connect to hardware connected to the server or the client? Or are the clients going to install a web server and host their own instance of your web app locally on their computers?

Comment: The hardware will be on client side and the web app will be stored on a hosting service (pending to be chosen). Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Then you won't be able to use PHP for it. PHP is a server side language, meaning that your PHP code will be executed on the server, and doesn't have anything to do with the client.

Comment: Then, is there a way to integrate the intended behavior with another language or an addon, or something different, still being managed by the app?